# Want to find a single character 'Y' in the data and it would be at any place in the list but has to be a single ''Y"

Tags: sql

Want to find a single character 'Y' in the data and it would be at any place in the list but has to be a single ''Y"

Sample Data:

```
Value
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNYNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNYNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNYNNNNNNNNNYNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNYNNNNNNYNNNNNNNYNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNYNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
YNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
```

Expecting result

```
Value
NNNNNNNNNYNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNYNN
NNNNNNNNNNYNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
YNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LIKE`:

```
where value like '%Y%' and
      value not like '%Y%Y%'
```

You could also use `replace()` and the length of the string.  Something like this:

```
where length(value) = length(replace(value, 'Y', '')) + 1
```

This is a little more convenient, if you wanted to find, say, between 3 and 7 "Y"s.